# How i can get list with names of all queues in remote websphere application server?

Tags: java, jms, websphere, ibm-mq

I connect to remote was with AdminClient and get list of queues with some code:

```
...
AdminClient client = new AdminClientFactory.createAdminClient(props);
Set<ObjectName> s = client.queryNames(new ObjectName("WebSphere:*"),null);
if (!s.isEmpty()){
     Iterator i = s.iterator();
     while (i.hasNext){
          ObjectName on = i.next();
          String type = on.getKeyProperty("type");
          if ("SIBQueuePoint".eqquals(type)){
               System.out.println(on.getKeyProperty("name");)
          }
     }
}
```

This list me queues with JMS provider "Default Messaging provider". But also, i have some queues with "Websphere MQ messaging provider", which not exist in this list.

How i can get list with all queues from all JMS providers?

Comment: Let me understand what you need. You want to export Queue Connection Factories and Queues? Or you need all of them including the Connetion Factories, Topic Connection Factories, Topics and Activation Specification?

Comment: @adimoise91 just Queue Connection Factories and Queues.

Comment: Do you have access to wsadmin commands? If you have, you can use some built-in functions. So tell me if you can use the wsadmin commands, because I have to know how to write the script for you.
I don't know how to write the script in java language. But if you want I can make a script in python for you and then if you understand the way to solve your problem you can try the method in java language. I am waiting for your answer.

Comment: @adimoise91 yes, i have access to wsadmin. If it possible, try write it, and i try port it to java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Srry for late. As i promise, here is the script in python language.

All you have to do is to replace your scope and your resource file.

```
import sys, java, java.io, java.lang

lineSeparator = java.lang.System.getProperty('line.separator')

def listMQQCF(scope):
    scopeID = AdminConfig.getid(scope)
    scopeName = scope[scope.rfind(":")+1:scope.rfind("/")]
    wmqQCFList = AdminConfig.list('MQQueueConnectionFactory', scopeID).split(lineSeparator)
    MQQCFListHeader = "\n#==== MQQueueConnectionFactoryList " + scopeName + " ===="
    MQQCFListHeader = MQQCFListHeader + "\n#[name, jndiName, ,description, queueManager, transportType, host, port, channel, ConmaxConn, ConminCon, SessionmaxConn, SessionminConn]\n"  
    MQQCFList = "MQQueueConnectionFactoryList = [\\\n"
    if (len(wmqQCFList) > 0):
        for wmqQCF in wmqQCFList:
            wmqQCFName = wmqQCF[wmqQCF.rfind("/")+1:wmqQCF.find("|")]
            if (scopeName == wmqQCFName):
                name = AdminConfig.showAttribute(wmqQCF, 'name')
                jndiName = AdminConfig.showAttribute(wmqQCF, 'jndiName')
                description = AdminConfig.showAttribute(wmqQCF, 'description')
                if (description == None): description = ""
                queueManager = AdminConfig.showAttribute(wmqQCF, 'queueManager')                
                transportType = AdminConfig.showAttribute(wmqQCF, 'transportType')
                host = AdminConfig.showAttribute(wmqQCF, 'host')
                port = AdminConfig.showAttribute(wmqQCF, 'port')
                channel = AdminConfig.showAttribute(wmqQCF, 'channel')
                connPool = AdminConfig.showAttribute(wmqQCF, 'connectionPool')
                sessionPool = AdminConfig.showAttribute(wmqQCF, 'sessionPool')
                connTimeout = AdminConfig.showAttribute(connPool, "connectionTimeout")
                maxConn = AdminConfig.showAttribute(connPool, "maxConnections")
                minConn = AdminConfig.showAttribute(connPool, "minConnections")
                reapTime = AdminConfig.showAttribute(connPool, "reapTime")
                unusedTimeout =  AdminConfig.showAttribute(connPool, "unusedTimeout")
                agedTimeout = AdminConfig.showAttribute(connPool, "agedTimeout")
                sesconnTimeout = AdminConfig.showAttribute(sessionPool, "connectionTimeout")
                sesmaxConn = AdminConfig.showAttribute(sessionPool, "maxConnections")
                sesminConn = AdminConfig.showAttribute(sessionPool, "minConnections")
                sesreapTime = AdminConfig.showAttribute(sessionPool, "reapTime")
                sesunusedTimeout =  AdminConfig.showAttribute(sessionPool, "unusedTimeout")
                sesagedTimeout = AdminConfig.showAttribute(sessionPool, "agedTimeout")
                MQQCFList = MQQCFList + "['" + name + "','" + jndiName + "','" + description + "','" +  queueManager + "','" + transportType + "','" + host + "','" + port + "','" + channel + "','" + maxConn + "','" + minConn + "','" + sesmaxConn + "','" + sesminConn + "'],\\\n"
    if (MQQCFList[len(MQQCFList)-3] == ","):
        MQQCFList = MQQCFList[0:len(MQQCFList)-3] + "]\n"
    else:
        MQQCFList = MQQCFList[0:len(MQQCFList)-2] + "]\n"
    return MQQCFListHeader + MQQCFList

def listMQQueue(scope):
    scopeID = AdminConfig.getid(scope)
    scopeName = scope[scope.rfind(":")+1:scope.rfind("/")]
    objdmgr = AdminControl.queryNames('WebSphere:type=Server,name=dmgr,*')
    version = objdmgr[objdmgr.find("version")+8:]
    wmqQueueList = AdminConfig.list('MQQueue', scopeID).split(lineSeparator)
    MQQueueListHeader = "\n#==== MQQueueList " + scopeName + "  ====\n#[name, jndiName, description, baseQueueName, baseQMgrName, persistence, priority, targetClient, messageBody]\n"
    MQQueueList = "MQQueueList = [\\\n"
    if (len(wmqQueueList) > 0) :
        for wmqQueue in wmqQueueList:
            wmqQueueName = wmqQueue[wmqQueue.rfind("/")+1:wmqQueue.find("|")]
            if (scopeName == wmqQueueName):
                name = AdminConfig.showAttribute(wmqQueue, 'name')
                jndiName = AdminConfig.showAttribute(wmqQueue, 'jndiName')
                description = AdminConfig.showAttribute(wmqQueue, 'description')
                if (description == None):   description = ""
                baseQueueName = AdminConfig.showAttribute(wmqQueue, 'baseQueueName')
                baseQMgrName = AdminConfig.showAttribute(wmqQueue, 'baseQueueManagerName')
                if (baseQMgrName == None):  baseQMgrName = ""
                persistence = AdminConfig.showAttribute(wmqQueue, 'persistence')    
                priority = AdminConfig.showAttribute(wmqQueue, 'priority')
                targetClient = AdminConfig.showAttribute(wmqQueue, 'targetClient')
                if (version =='8'):
                    messageBody = AdminConfig.showAttribute(wmqQueue, 'messageBody')
                else:
                    messageBody = ""                
                MQQueueList = MQQueueList + "['" + name + "','" + jndiName + "','" + description + "','" + baseQueueName + "','" + baseQMgrName + "','" + persistence + "','" + priority + "','" + targetClient + "','" + messageBody + "'],\\\n"               
            #endif
    if (MQQueueList[len(MQQueueList)-3] == ","):
        MQQueueList = MQQueueList[0:len(MQQueueList)-3] + "]\n"
    else:
        MQQueueList = MQQueueList[0:len(MQQueueList)-2] + "]\n"
    return MQQueueListHeader + MQQueueList


#===============================================
#MAIN
#===============================================    

filename='resources.txt'
scope='/Cell:CellName/ServerCluster:ClusterName/'


objItemFileOutputStream = java.io.FileOutputStream(fileName, 1)
scopeID = AdminConfig.getid(scope)
if ( scopeID <> ""):
    list = listRes(objType, scope)
    objItemFileOutputStream.write(list)
else:
    print "\n" + scope + "\t Failed: Incorrect scopes!\n"
objItemFileOutputStream.close()
```

Good Luck!